# compare the end date of an year and the start date of this year+1

Tags: sql

```
year X+1 2009 2008-12-21 00:00:00.000 2009-12-28 00:00:00.000 
year X 2008 2007-12-26 00:00:00.000 2008-12-20 00:00:00.000
```

i want to compare the end date of year x (2008) to the start date of year x+1 (2009)

Comment: Do you have an actual query here?  What version of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, Oracle, etc.)?

Comment: How do you want to compare them?  *Compare* is a very general term...  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Check the `LAG` function, this can be used to access the 'previous' row's data: `LAG(end_date) OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY start_date)`

Comment: thanks please for this reply,


in this query , it compares the start date and the date of the same line. but i want to compare the start date of year +1 (2009) with the end date of year (2008)

select PersonID, Year(taxeDate),PeriodeStartDate ,PeriodeEndDate 

from dbo.Payment where PeriodeStartDate < PeriodeEndDate .

Comment: could u please do an exemple with my query , please

Answer (score 0):

Applying `LAG` to your sample query:

```
select *
from
 (
   select PersonID, Year(taxeDate),PeriodeStartDate ,PeriodeEndDate,
      LAG(PeriodeEndDate) -- previous row's PeriodeEndDate
      OVER (PARTITION BY PersonID
            ORDER BY PeriodeStartDate) as prev_EndDate
   from dbo.Payment 
 ) as dt
where PeriodeStartDate < prev_EndDate
```

Comment: Thanks so much , this really helped me , i am so greatful for u .